# Where can we find the App authenticity failure reports in worklight console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an app which has app authenticity enabled, I wanna see number of apps failed authenticity in my worklight console  and its device details is this possible if yes where do I see it.

I.E app authenticity failure report on worklight console..

I see something in analyticsconsole/security.. will this help

Please find the below image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticity is not counted separately from other authentication failures. You can submit a feature request for this: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Idan, But I see something in analytics console/security failures and attempts for each realm. will this help. Because I don't see failure count showing correctly even if there is authenticity failure. I have added an image in my question for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Analytics console does not have capability to show App Authenticity failures.